# Count instances in table and capture the id of every instance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, count

What I'm trying to do is search through my table and count the instances of a letter, and store the ID of each instance in mysql and php (PDO).

What I had been messing around with is this:

```
$user = 'john';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, SUBSTR(surname, 1, 1) as surname_init,COUNT(*) as count FROM first_table WHERE user = :user GROUP BY surname_init ORDER BY count DESC");
$stmt->bindValue(":user", $user);

$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($row);
```

This is the result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'surname_init' => string 'B' (length=1)
      'count' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'surname_init' => string 'D' (length=1)
      'count' => string '1' (length=1)
```

So I have two results: B has 2 instances, D has one. However "B" has only one resulting id returned from two.

Is this possible? I think I'm missing something here..

Comment: that is because you are doing group by surname_init. You can either get distinct ids or count but not both according to your logic. MySQL is just returning the first ID that is see for the surnames starting with B along with the count.

Comment: ah, so theres no way to get both?

Comment: a nested query maybe. Have you tried that ?

Comment: nope, but I'll have a look. Thanks!

Comment: it is but it goes against the basic of count and group by. By very definition, when you do a group by, you are grouping rows based on some criteria so that you can get a count. But if you need to get the individual rows that make that count, then you have to somehow "uncount" it, if that makes sense.

Comment: it does yes, but i think i'll need to sit down for 20 mins afterwards

Comment: look at the answer. See if that helps. Even if it does not work exactly the way you want, it should atleast clarify the concept and should be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get all rows that matched the group by, like:

```sql
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS id_list,
    SUBSTR(surname, 1, 1) as surname_init,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM first_table
WHERE user = :user
GROUP BY surname_init
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY` and `SEPARATOR` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
$user = 'john';
// use this to get unique starting characters for surnames for the user John
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUBSTR(surname, 1, 1) as `surname_init`, 
                       COUNT(*) as `count` FROM first_table 
                       WHERE user = :user GROUP BY 
                       surname_init ORDER BY count DESC");
$stmt->bindValue(":user", $user);
$stmt->execute();
$rows1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows1 as $row1){
    echo "<BR>Starting Letter: " . $row1['surname_init'];
    echo "<BR>Count: " . $row1['count'];

    // now get all the IDs for this user that have the 
    // surnames starting with this alphabet
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ID, SUBSTR(surname, 1, 1) as `surname_init`, 
                       FROM first_table 
                       WHERE user = :user 
                       AND surname LIKE :surname");
    $stmt->bindValue(":user", $user);
    $stmt->bindValue(":surname", $row1['surname_init']."%");

    $stmt->execute();
    $rows2 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows2 as $row2){
        // do insert based on ID here
    }        
}
```